# Backbone Collections and Handlebars each

Tags: templates, coffeescript, each, handlebars.js

I'm passing a collection called rowCollectionTest to a handlebar template and I think there is  a syntax issue.

My handlebars template reads:

```
`<table id = "tableId" width= "600px" border + 1">
     {{#each row}}
     <tr>
        <td> {{ this.car }} <td>
        <td> {{ this.beans }} <td>
        <td> {{ this.exercise }} <td> 
        <td> {{ this.iron }} <td>
     </tr>`
```

and I am passing in a rowCollectionTest, which is a collection of two rows (to see if I can make this work).

To pass in the values I do

```
@$el.find("#searchContainerId").append(Handlebars.templates["resultsPage"](
    row: rowCollectionTest
)}
```

I'm getting an error in my template file, so I suspect there's a syntax error there. What's going on?

Answer (score 3):

You have to close the `{{#each}}` and you should close your table. Also, `border + 1` isn't a valid HTML attribute, I think you want `border=1`:

```
<table id = "tableId" width="600px" border="1">
  {{#each row}}
  <tr>
    <td> {{ this.car }} </td>
    <td> {{ this.beans }} </td>
    <td> {{ this.exercise }} </td> 
    <td> {{ this.iron }} </td>
  </tr>
  {{/each}}
</table>
```

I also fixed your closing `</td>` tags.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/Ha6du/

Comment: is this.car valid? Because I've saved something to the car property of row, and row is definitely something and has the two models that I've saved( I checked on console), but console now tells me that this.car is illegal.

Comment: @praks5432: What exactly is `rowCollectionTest`?